# Plugin for creating noise / texture patterns?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, plugin, noise

I am looking for a plugin that will help me creating noise/texture patterns. I have included a few images for reference. Do anyone have some ideas in mind? Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Kresdjan and welcome to GDSE. You haven't added any tag about which application you use. My guess is Photoshop?

Comment: Hi. Weclome to GDSE. None of these examples are noise. Also the first one is nothing like the others which are dither patterns, typically created when turning images into Indexed colour mode.  What software do you have access to?  Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/130651/edit) to supply more information. Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks. Thanks for replying. @BillyKerr you are right, those are ended different. I might try a few examples with turning images into indexed color mode. I have access to Adobe and Affinity suite.

Comment: Yeah, try that.  Any decent raster image editor can do this - e.g. Photoshop, GIMP, etc.  No need for a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples you show are not simple noise or textures.

The first example seems to be *hand-drawn lines* which follows the shape. Easiest way to make this would be to simply draw the pattern manually (although some automated version of this might exist).

The other examples look like *dithering*. More specifically *stipple* or *stochastic* dithering. These are not just a pattern which you can fill an area with. They are a way of turning smooth gradients into two colors where the density of the pattern creates the different tints of the color.

As @BillyKerr mentions you could try to see what happens with the dithering methods available in Photoshop. Try to convert a grayscale image to either *Indexed Color* or *Bitmap* and play around with the different methods. I've also been very interested in these kind of dithering, but found that none of the built-in methods and effects in Photoshop can really create that effect.

I've found a plug-in called [*Pixeology Artistic Halftone*](http://www.pixeology.com/ArtisticHalftone/features.html) which can do some very nice stipple and stochastic dithering. It's not free though. There is a free trial which has all the functionality, but it leaves blocks of the image unprocessed.

Comment: Just for fun, here's a link to my [attempt at a stippler application](http://madswolff.dk/projects/Stippler/) written in Javascript. It's very much work in progress and might be changed or removed later. It uses 2-D collision detection to move thousands of virtual balls around until they all find a position where they don't overlap each other. The current example takes about 70 seconds to finish on my computer. When it's done an svg is created and can be downloaded.